# Dynamically choose SQL Server or Oracle database

Tags: c#, oracle, sql-server-2008, data-access

I have an application that allows my user to run queries against a database of their choice. The database can be either SQL server or Oracle. this method accepts two parameters from another class, first parameter is the connection string to the database the user chooses, and the second is the database type. that part works fine. what I am trying to do is cut back on the code I need to write and not type the query and connection stuff over and over. so, I would like to do something like this. Obviously this wont work, but I'm open to most solutions.

```
public void createTable(string connectstring, string rdbms)
{
    if (rdbms == "oracle")
    {
        con = new OracleConnection(connectionString);
        con.Open();
        OracleCommand query = con.CreateCommand();
    }
    else if (rdbms == "SQL Server")
    {
        con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand query = con.CreateCommand();
    }
    else 
    {
      // broke
    }

    query.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE " + RndName + 
       " (Col0 Varchar(10),Col1 Varchar(10), Col2 Varchar(10))";
    query.ExecuteNonQuery();

    con.Close();
    executeInsertTransactions(connectstring);
}
```

Comment: `*Connection` *should* implement [`IDbConnection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnection.aspx) and likewise, `*Command` *should* implement [`IDbCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idbcommand.aspx). (There are a number of DB-specificness still, however, but for a *simple* case using the interfaces as so should be OK.)

Answer (score 2):

This problem is generally solved via interfaces. There may be these common interfaces:

IConnection
IDataProvider
IRepository

Implement interfaces using MySql database, such as class MySqlConnection : IConnection. For Oracle, add class MsOracleConnection : IConnection.

Ideally you should abstract all the functionality into common interfaces. You will have to provide implementations for each database/storage engine you want to support. At runtime, you will use IoC container and DI principle to set up the current implementation. All the child dependencies will use interfaces passed in as parameters to constructor (or properties or methods)

Answer (score 2):

You can create more abstract code by leveraging the framework's [`DbProviderFactory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wda6c36e.aspx) and using the obtained [`Db*`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9hy8csk1.aspx) classes.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim con As System.Data.IDbConnection
Dim cmd As System.Data.IDbCommand                        
                       Select Case ConDBType
                            Case TypeDatabase.SqlServer
                                con = New OleDbConnection(CN.ConnectionString)
                                cmd = New OleDbCommand
                            Case TypeDatabase.MySql
                                con = New MySqlConnection(CNMySql.ConnectionString)
                                cmd = New MySqlCommand
                            Case TypeDatabase.Access
                                Call InitNameing()
                                ConDBAccess.DataSource = PreparToRootNameing() & "\T" & NAME_SYSTEMDB
                                con = New OleDbConnection(CN.ConnectionString)
                                cmd = New OleDbCommand
                       End Select
                       cmd.Connection = con
                       con.Open()
                       cmd.CommandText = SQLUpdate
                       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```